OpenFaces JSF - Null Pointer OpenFacesResourceHandler.isExternalResource on weblogic
I've been given a OLD application that we're migrating to weblogic .Whilst we should probably look at rewriting eventually to bide us some time we're trying to get it up on weblogic. We've got the application up but when we come to submit anything vi commandButtons (even non openfaces ones) we get the following error. Even if I remove the openfaces totally from the jsf page and backing bean it seems to hit it. So I assume its something backend related.
Has anyone got any hints of where to look for this?
`####<May 24, 2024 10:58:11,513 AM EDT> <Error> <javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context> <*removed_server_details*> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '15' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<anonymous>> <> <017ee624-69b8-4240-81e2-462b625ca26b-0000ccdd> <1716562691513> <[severity-value: 8] [rid: 0] > <BEA-000000> <java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.openfaces.application.OpenFacesResourceHandler.isExternalResource(OpenFacesResourceHandler.java:96)
    at org.openfaces.application.OpenFacesResourceHandler.getRendererTypeForResourceName(OpenFacesResourceHandler.java:78)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.renderComponentResources(PartialViewContextImpl.java:482)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:314)
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialViewContext.processPartial(PrimePartialViewContext.java:46)
    at javax.faces.context.PartialViewContextWrapper.processPartial(PartialViewContextWrapper.java:228)
    at org.openfaces.ajax.PartialViewContext.processPartial(PartialViewContext.java:131)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.encodeChildren(UIViewRoot.java:1102)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1647)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:442)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:170)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:102)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:76)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:199)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.executeLifecyle(FacesServlet.java:708)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:451)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:295)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:353)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:82)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:32)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:82)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3866)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3829)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:344)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.processSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2502)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2351)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2326)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2304)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1779)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1733)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:272)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
    at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
    at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:651)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:420)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:360)`

I've tried removing openfaces from the page i'm accessing. I'm wondering if its a setup issue.
